# Sending mail with images in to Yahoo accounts

Tags: yahoo-mail, images, email-client

Has anyone had problems over the past few days with Yahoo Mail not showing images?

I have a template that is fine for all the big clients that has been worked on quite extensively that has been absolutely fine. However since yesterday any images in the mail don't want to show up. Or they flick on for a second and then disappear and just show the placeholder. The images exist as they work in all other test clients and I have confirmed this via direct links to the image.

I can't find any information on this issue anywhere and it is beginning to be a problem!

Comment: Is this consistent across browsers and operating systems?

Comment: All browsers it seems. Firefox shows one of the images, I just tested in IE and, I see none of the images, just the placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed!

We had disabled image hotlinking on the server.... DUH! Strange how it only seemed to effect Yahoo Mail though. Ah well.